# Disk Space on Virtual Machiene

Tags: disk

I am not sure what is wrong, I have 150GB Disk space on my Linux VM, and though the Disk Analyzer utility shows "/" is full, with 45GB only whilst the root "/" is mounted to 150GB disk.

Any Idea what is going on and how to solve it?

Thanking you.

Jamils

[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwy7A.jpg)

[Disk Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bh4A.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you [edit] your question by adding some essential information like lsblk, df, etc?

Comment: and the version of ubuntu

Comment: Just a Guess...Disk Space is allocated Dynamically.